# Indexing in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Why do we use index in "where clause"? Is it an auto generated number ans starts 
from  zero? Simple example would be really helpful.

```
var query =... Where((p,index)..)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an auto-generated number that starts from zero.

Use it whenever you need access to the index in your query.

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var evenLetters = alphabet.Where((p, index) => (index % 2) == 1);
var oddLetters = alphabet.Where((p, index) => (index % 2) == 0);
```

Comment: Thank you Luke  for the example

Answer (score 1):

The index should refer to the index of the current item in the collection (the zero based iteration).

There is a simple example [on this page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/LINQ/UseindexwhenqueryingarraywithLINQ.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
var oddElements = query.Where((p, index) => index % 2 == 1);
```